# Azure Cognitive Services: Face Find Similar 'BadArgument', 'Argument faceListId and faceIds cannot be provided at the same time.'.'

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face

I am new to Azure Cognitive Services.  I am using python 3.5 and the Azure Face service, specifically the "Face - Find Similar" API.   I am getting an error formatting the Post JSON body.  The documentation says that I should either provide a single faceId or a list of faces in a face list, e.g., 'extended_family'.   In my case, I want to use the face list. I do not know how to format the faceID parameter in the JSON so that call processes the face list.  I have tried different alternatives to setting faceId to '{}' or 'Null', '', 'False', and this results in errors.

Below is my JSON body for my POST:

```
{'faceId': '97522b8b-02b6-4115-99e0-6dc1f5d45f51', 'faceIds': ['97522b8b-   02b6-4115-99e0-6dc1f5d45f51', '0ca8f3e4-edf1-4c14-b926-3b47eae7e29c', '2fadbb12-b10b-4761-aaaa-c50f1dc765c3', '56f464d5-b388-4fc7-9051-6991cf5f1d0d', '29931480-632e-40b6-aa0c-9e03e36e95f9', '7a8085b2-2013-4742-a51a-a5543a0347e8'], 'faceListId': 'extended_family', 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': 'matchPerson'}
```

Since faceId is populated, I get:

```
error:  'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Argument faceListId and faceIds cannot be provided at the same time.'
```

If I leave faceId blank, such as:

```
{'faceId': '', 'faceIds': ['824e3d83-a94f-4ef2-949e-55a55b2ef256', '51f3c1a5-4e16-4b14-89fa-f1342a2c46ec', '0480d2e0-ff05-44de-b3d8-94408277b1c5', 'c7d767fb-0fbe-46c8-b7af-2c8f675bfd8d', 'ca7e82a7-cd3f-417b-bffa-77c9d47c1439', 'f7130e90-9e1f-428a-a773-93c87932a420'], 'faceListId': 'extended_family', 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': 'matchPerson'}
```

I get the following:

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Request body is invalid.'}}
```

If I remove the faceId term from the JSON:

```
{'faceIds': ['690feffd-5c86-47d7-ac3c-224b0eafa90f', '936564e0-31aa-43e3-916e-c7b236bea8e0', '614c04cb-4375-44c8-b393-89d64b4c1ebd', 'a29f8e5c-50ba-4bb8-8bf8-98e356a9125a', '073d7865-2aaf-4806-9bef-ddca478137ea', '7e416e83-5973-4aa1-b1fc-3a25b5174bb3'], 'faceListId': 'andersen_extended_family', 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': 'matchPerson'}
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Face ID is invalid.'}}
```

My code is as follows:

```
facelist = list()  #This is populated upstream using the Face Detect API
facelistid = 'extended_family'
faceid = ''

payload = {'faceId': faceid, 'faceIds':facelist,'faceListId':facelistid, 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned':20,'mode': "matchPerson"}
req = requests.post(serviceurlpersongroup, data = json.dumps(payload)  , headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key})
jinfo = req.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message explained, `faceListId` and `faceIds` **(not faceId)** should not be provided at the same time. So the `payload` you use should be

```
payload = {'faceId': faceid, 'faceListId': facelistid, 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': "matchPerson"}
```

or

```
payload = {'faceId': faceid, 'faceIds': facelist, 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': "matchPerson"}
```

Feel free to update if you have any further questions.